# sql subquery update with 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables

post

```
int_PostId , dtm_Publishdate               createddate
1             2013-02-07 21:12:03.247
2             2013-03-07 21:12:03.247
3             2013-03-07 21:12:03.247
```

and postmeta

```
int_postmetaid, metakey ,     metavalue ,     int_PostId , int createddate
   1              chk           en                1             2013-02-07  
   2              chk           ps                1             2013-02-07  
   3              chk           cs                1             2013-02-07  
   4             publishdate     2013-03-07       1             2013-02-07
   5              chk           en                2             2013-02-07  
   6              chk           ps                2             2013-02-07  
   7              chk           cs                2             2013-02-07    
   8             publishdate     2013-03-07       2             2013-02-07
   9              chk           en                3             2013-02-07  
   10              chk           ps               3             2013-02-07  
   11              chk           cs               3             2013-02-07
```

i want to update post's dtm_Publishdate column with these condition. i want to do it in one query

1) if the ***publishdate*** metakey exist in the postmeta table  update post's ***dtm_Publishdate*** with it's metavalue

2) if it doesn's exist then update the post's dtm_Publishdate with it's createddate

i am really stuck with the condition scenario. can someonehelp?

Comment: if there's no publishdate, which metavalue should win?  the max(createdate)?

Comment: right, but you have 3 of them, for metavalues en, ps, and cs

Comment: @Beth - the post's created date: Post.CreatedDate. Not the meta-post's created date.

Comment: so int_postID = 3's dtm_publishdate would be changed to null?

Comment: @Beth Sure looks that way. Mazhar, can you please clarify your sample data and expected behavior?

Comment: int_postID = 3's dtm_publishdate would be changed to it's corresponding  createddate

Comment: because it doesn't have any publishdate in postmeta table

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're on SQL Server 2008 or later, use [the MERGE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

```
MERGE INTO post as Target
USING (SELECT int_PostId,metavalue 
    FROM postmeta 
    WHERE metakey='publishdate') 
    as Source (int_PostId,metavalue)
ON Source.int_PostId = Target.int_PostId
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Target.dtm_Publishdate = Source.metavalue
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Target.dtm_Publishdate = Target.createddate
```

You may need to cast the metavalue column to a DateTime type in the WHEN MATCHED clause.

Answer (score 0):

if there's only ever one publishdate row in postmeta, you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE post 
SET dtm_publishdate =
    CASE WHEN pd.metavalue IS NOT NULL
        THEN metavalue
        ELSE createddate
    END
FROM
    post p LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        int_postID, metavalue
    FROM 
        post p INNER JOIN
        postmeta m ON
        p.int_postID = m.int_postID
    WHERE
        metakey = 'publishdate') pd ON
    p.int_postid = pd.int_postID
```